# Python, Cv2, numpy to detect a picture in another picture

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I am using these codes to detect if a small picture is a part of a big picture. (or take it as, if the small picture can be found in the big picture)

this is the BIG picture

[image: this is the BIG picture]

this is the SMALL picture

[image]

It works fine and give me the x_coordinate of where the small picture starts.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

big_pic = cv2.imread("c:\\big.jpg")
small_pic = cv2.imread('c:\\small.jpg')
res = cv2.matchTemplate(big_pic,small_pic,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.99
loc = np.where (res >= threshold)
x_coordinate = list(loc[0])

print x_coordinate
```

However, when I want to specify the detection area in the big picture – that is, if the small picture can be found in certain part of the big picture – it fails.

```
big_pic = cv2.imread("c:\\big.jpg")
target_area = big_pic[0:0, 238:220]

small_pic = cv2.imread('c:\\small.jpg')
res = cv2.matchTemplate(target_area,small_pic,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.99
loc = np.where (res >= threshold)
x_coordinate = list(loc[0])

print x_coordinate
```

The error says:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1) in cv::crossCorr, file ......\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp, line 658
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\finding picture.py", line 8, in 
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(target_area,small_pic,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: ......\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:658: error: (-215) corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function cv::crossCorr

What went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `big_pic[0:0, 238:220]` seems wrong.

Comment: Please include the complete traceback. These errors are cryptic since they are raised from the lower-level modules...

Comment: @Divakar, thank you. what's the right way to specify an area?

Comment: @MarkK `big_pic[x1:x2, y1:y2]`, instead of `big_pic[x1:y1, x2:y2]`

Comment: No I guess it must be `big_pic[y1:y2, x1:x2]` @Rightleg

Comment: @ZdaR It's a matter of point of view. All modules out there use different coordinate systems anyway, so you always to think again from the start. The idea is that it's not `(point1, point2)` but `((point1.1, point2.1), (point1.2, point2.2))`

Comment: But we are talking about `numpy` syntax specifically here. If it was a *matter of point of view*, then OP hadn't experienced the error.

Comment: @Rightleg, ZdaR, thank both of you the guidance on thinking. I try both and it works, as the Small picture is a nearly a square. I will try a rectangle to find out.

Comment: @MarkK No there's certainly a difference in orientation, what I mean is that since all libraries and frameworks and modules and so on use their own coordinate systems, so you'll always have to try before being sure of which to use.

Comment: @Zadr so...are one of you guys going to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [y,y1 : x,x1] is the right format. So the credit shall go to @ZdaR.

Just to post an edited example, using a rectangle shape SMALL.

this is the BIG picture

[image: BIG]

this is the SMALL picture

[image: SMALL]

The target area is,

```
[0,0] [300,220]. # Reading as [x, y] and [x1, y1].
```

They are the top left point and bottom right point in the BIG.

Made the code as following:

```
big_pic = cv2.imread("c:\\big.jpg")

target_area = big_pic[0:220, 0:300]   # [y,y1 : x,x1]   # it returns a result.
target_area = big_pic[0:300, 0:220]   # [x,x1 : y,y1]   # it doesn’t return a result.

small_pic = cv2.imread('c:\\small.jpg')
res = cv2.matchTemplate(target_area,small_pic,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.99
loc = np.where (res >= threshold)
x_coordinate = list(loc[0])

print x_coordinate
```